# How to open file in default application. Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

How to open file in its default application using Ruby scripts?

Let us say, I have folder with files .txt .doc .rb and I would like open them with Notepad, Word, and RubyMine respectively. I assume that all files have their default applications to open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work (untested, as I'm not on a Windows machine now):

```
file_to_open = "c:\path\to\file.txt"
system %{cmd /c "start #{file_to_open}"}
```

For reference, this can also be done on OS X:

```
file_to_open = "/path/to/file.txt"
system %{open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

Comment: Only now I can accept it ;) because Stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept answers earlier than 8mins

Comment: No worries, posted another question, which goes a bit deeper into file openings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476484/how-to-open-file-in-default-application-and-on-specified-line-ruby

Comment: Is there a cross-platform way of doing this? Don't want to rely on terminal strings for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use the [OS gem](https://github.com/rdp/os)

```
require 'os'
OS.open_file_command
    => "start" # or open on mac, or xdg-open on linux (all designed to open a file)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

```
UI.openURL(filepath)
```

On MacOS:

```
system %{open '#{filepath}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to add a dependency, there is a gem [launchy](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy).

```rb
Launchy.open(path_or_uri)
```

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball I'm not affiliated with it.